# How to get notified when a bidirectional stream is cancelled

Tags: grpc-c++

I'm creating a bidirectional stream for sending messages from a gRPC server to its client.
The server is created using:

```cpp
...
grpc::ServerBuilder builder;
builder.AddListeningPort(server_address, grpc::InsecureServerCredentials());
builder.RegisterService(this);
std::unique_ptr<grpc::Server> server(builder.BuildAndStart());
server->Wait();
...
```

Here is an excerpt from the service definition .proto file:

```
...
rpc OpenCallBackChannel(stream CallBackAPIResponseMessageToServer) returns (stream CallBackAPIRequestMessageFromServer) {}
...
```

The client calls the server's method `OpenCallBackChannel` to start a bidirectional communications session. In the server-side handler for this method I save the context and stream passed to this handler, say `_context` & `_stream`, respectively.
I send messages to client using `_stream.Write`, and read response messages from client using `_stream.Read`.

Using `_context->IsCancelled()` I can check if the channel has been dropped before I try to read from it using `_stream.Read`.

Is there a method to know when the bidirectional channel is no longer valid without having to call `_context->IsCancelled()` periodically?

BR

Comment: Cancelation is handled a little differently across languages and I'm not sure how you should do this in C++, but here's a couple of links that might help you: [cancellation user guide:](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/cancellation/), [C++ cancellation example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples/cpp/cancellation).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment, your reference to the cancellation user guide will be useful for others. I've just posted, in general terms, the solution path I took.

Answer (score 0):

As I was using the synchronous API, at the end I created a worker thread and passed the stream. According to grpc's documentation writing/reading is thread-safe for this stream.

When clients close/cancel the channel, `_stream.Read()` fails, and `_context->IsCancelled()` returns true. That's the moment for ending the stream reading thread and to notify the rest of the application of this event.

I pass read messages to a received-messages queue, read them from where I need them, with a read timeout which is something I needed too.

Maybe not the neatest solution, surely not compared to the async API, but it works.